# Getting non-master branch from Cocoapods?

Tags: cocoapods, alamofire, swift2, xcode7, swifty-json

I've been using [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/tree/xcode7) and [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/tree/swift-2.0) in a project.  Recently I downloaded XCode 7 beta.  Both SwiftyJSON and Alamofire have separate, non-master branches for Swift 2.  Is there a way to get these via CocoaPods, or do I need to install them in the traditional way?

I tried searching on the CocoaPods website to see if these branches had been submitted as separate Pods, but nothing came up.  I'm wondering if there is a Podfile syntax that allows you to get a non-master branch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify any branch from the repository in your Podfile.

Example I'm using for Alamofire:

```
pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :branch => 'swift-2.0'
```

Change the line(s) in your Podfile then run `pod install` again.

---

There's also this alternative syntax:

```
pod 'Alamofire', git: 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', branch: 'swift-2.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Update to the current answer. The line above now returns git errors complaining that the 'swift-2.0' branch is not found.
Use this form instead:

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 2.0'
```