# Alamofire with Xcode 7

Tags: cocoapods, swift2, alamofire, xcode7-beta4

I'm using Xcode 7.0 beta 4 (7A165t). I want to add the Alamofire library but it's always failing.

I am using the last Cocoapods version.

My Podfile is:

```
pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :branch => 'swift-2.0'
```

Is it possible to use it in Xcode 7 with Swift 2.0?

**UPDATE**

When I run:

```
pod install
```

I get this:

> Installing Alamofire (2.0.0-beta.1)
>      [!] Pods written in Swift can only be integrated as frameworks; this feature is still in beta. Add `use_frameworks!` to your Podfile or target to opt into using it. The Swift Pod being used is: Alamofire

Comment: You've got a typo in your example. Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31334205/getting-non-master-branch-from-cocoapods/31336908#31336908

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do what the error message tells you to and add `use_frameworks!` to your Podfile. Here's mine as an example:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :osx, '10.10'
use_frameworks!
pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :branch => 'swift-2.0'
```

For iOS instead of OS X, replace the platform line with `platform :ios, '8.0'` or equivalent.

Comment: But should I use it in Xcode 6.4? Can I do this in Xcode 7 beta 5?

Comment: Your question was specific about Swift2/Xcode7... so my answer is for Xcode7, yes, whatever the beta number. But for using Alamofire with Swift1/Xcode6, you don't need to specifiy a branch, use a normal Podfile. This answer is for Swift2 specifically.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I did it. Add the podfile with the info you provied. Changed to platform: ios, '8.3'. Open xcworkspace and add import Alamofire to ViewController.swift. It gives back the error: "Cannot load underlying module for 'Alamofire'. Any idea?

Comment: Yes, this is Xcode freaking out because of cached data. Do "Product -> Clean" and restart Xcode. If this is not enough, search for "clear derived data" and do it too. But just cleaning product should work.

Comment: It worked thank you very much. Just one more question please. If I want to add SwiftyJSON can I do it in the same Podfile? Or is there a better way?

Comment: You're welcome. :) For SwiftyJSON I don't use Cocoapods, I'm just using it by dropping the `SwiftyJSON.swift` file into my project. But I *guess* you can add the Cocoapods version to your Podfile, yes.

Comment: I'll try it. But when add it to my project and import SwitfyJSON => 'No such module 'SwiftyJSON'... And the SwiftyJSON.swift has several errors.

Comment: Don't forget to download the specific Swift2 branch of SwiftyJSON for using with Xcode7 :) You can select the branch in GitHub before downloading. https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/tree/xcode7

Comment: I didn't realize you were doing that: when using the simple SwiftyJSON.swift file, you *don't* have to declare `import SwiftyJSON`. Remove this import line and it will work by itself. :)

Comment: upsss.. Sorry I am new to swift.. Thank you so much. No it's time to learn how to read a JSON.. ahaha. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

this is how mi CocoaPods file looks and im currently working in swift2.0 in Xcode7 Beta

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'RESTEST' do
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 2.0'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
```

I'm using both SwiftyJSON and Alamofire, if you have any trouble using both libraries we are here to help, Greetings